# Google Sheet importxml - How to retrieve only the 1st value?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IFERROR(importxml(B1, "//title/text()"),A1)
```

I'm using `Google Script` to input the above into `C1` and fill down.

It works fine when there is only 1 title in each result, but returns an error when there are more than 1 :

> **Error
>   Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C2**

How can I limit the result to just the first title tag found, or (probably better) modify the `IFERROR` to handle this array 'error'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      =IFERROR(importxml(B1, "(//title/text())[1]"),A1)
```

Or

```
     =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(importxml(B1, "//title/text()"),A1),1,1)
```

Mark this as answer, If it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for both. I combined them and it's perfect for my needs. =IFERROR(importxml(B1, "(//title/text())[1]"),ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(importxml(B1, "//title/text()"),A1),1,1))

Comment: =IMPORTXML(B5, "(//meta[@name='description']/@content)[1]") this worked for me, where in B5 there is the page URL